# RESTful API http method for a beforehead unknown method

Tags: rest

I'm implementing a voting system (like/dislike) according to RESTful API and wondering what should I do if the intention is unknown while a request.
My real case:
If a user voting the first time - create a vote, if the user already has a vote - delete his vote (a vote can be only `like` or `dislike`, not `0`). So what HTTP method and HTTP status code are suitable for this?

Answer (score 1):

`PUT` sounds like a good option for this. `PUT` is used to create or replace the resource at the target uri.

```
PUT /article/[id]/myvote
```

When the vote is created, you can return `201`. When it is overwritten, you can return `204` or `200`.

Answer (score 1):

> My real case: If a user voting the first time - create a vote, if the user already has a vote - delete his vote (a vote can be only like or dislike, not 0).

How would you do it with a web site?

You would have some HTML page with a form on it; the form would include some input controls to collect information from the user.  When the user submits the form, the browser would -- using the standardized HTML form processing rules, use the data and metadata of the form to create an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` document, which it would send to the server as described by the form.

Supposing for this particular case that the action of voting is not "essentially read only", we would choose a form method that is not safe, which is to say POST.

The status codes to be returned would be exactly the same status codes (with the same meanings) that every other POST on the web uses.  In particular, if the origin server successfully handles the request, then one of the 2xx status codes would be returned, with an appropriate entity and meta data.

If you aren't sure which 2xx code to use, 200 is the safe bet.

Remember, the world wide web is *the* reference implementation in the REST architectural style.  You won't be far off if you storyboard a website, then use that to guide your api design.

---

There are other alternatives, that require a bit more thinking.  One would be to treat the voter's ballot as a *document* that is stored on the origin server.  The voter might GET a copy of his ballot, make local changes to it, and then request that the origin server apply those changes to its local copy of the ballot.

In that design, we would normally use PUT to copy our local edits to the web server; and the server would -- as before -- return some 2xx status code if request was successful.

The client, of course, will need to understand the representation of the ballot well enough to make the appropriate edits to it.  You'll also need some sort of link convention that allows the client to find the right instance of ballot to edit.

The *actual* representation on the server doesn't need to be a document, of course.  The document delivered to the origin server might instead be copied into rows in a relational database (an arbitrary example).

---

In the specific case of associating a representation (document) with a resource that previously didn't have one (in other words, if `GET /ballot` would have returned a 404), then the HTTP standard requires that you respond with a 201 status code, rather than a 200 status code, and include the appropriate metadata to identify the newly created resource.

```
GET /ballots/68D7165A-D172-4E32-84F3-E494A01B5C8E
```

```
404 Not Found

Ballot: /ballots/68D7165A-D172-4E32-84F3-E494A01B5C8E
has not yet been submitted
```

```
PUT /ballots/68D7165A-D172-4E32-84F3-E494A01B5C8E
Content-Type: text/plain

LIKE
```

```
201 Created
Location: /ballots/68D7165A-D172-4E32-84F3-E494A01B5C8E

Thank you for voting!
```

```
GET /ballots/68D7165A-D172-4E32-84F3-E494A01B5C8E
```

```
200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

LIKE
```